# Data saved not corresponding with database content SQLite litepal

Tags: java, sqlite, runnable

I'm new to android development.

I'm trying to save data to the database from `json string`

```
[{
    "question": "Who is the 'Modern Love' rock star singer?",
    "imageUrl": "https://postimg.cc/2VL1Y1jd",

    "answerOptions": [
        "Jimi Hendrix",
        "David Bowie",
        "Jim Morrison",
        "Elvis Presley"
    ],

    "correctAnswer": "David Bowie"
}]
```

and in mainActivity `onCreate` I have:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    Quiz quiz = list.get(i);
    quiz.save();
}
```

which works perfectly well hence when I debug I have:

[image]

But when I view the database file, the subList of `answerOptions` is missing:

[image]

Thus when I try to `runOnUiThread`, the list at `litePal.findall` doesn't correspond with the `Quiz.class`

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        List<Quiz> list = LitePal.findAll(Quiz.class);
        QuizAdapter quizAdapter = new QuizAdapter(list, MainActivity.this);
        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(quizAdapter);
    }
});
```

```
class Quiz extends LitePalSupport {
    String question;
    String imageUrl;
    String [] answerOptions;
    String correctAnswer;
}
```

Is there any possible solution/alternative to this approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by changing my data structure:

```
[{
    "question": "Who is the 'Modern Love' rock star singer?",
    "imageUrl": "https://postimg.cc/2VL1Y1jd",
    "one": "Jimi Hendrix",
    "two": "David Bowie",
    "three": "Jim Morrison",
    "four": "Elvis Presley",
    "correctAnswer": "David Bowie"
}]
```

Then adjust my class accordingly:

```
public class Quiz extends LitePalSupport {
    String question;
    String imageUrl;
    String one;
    String two;
    String three;
    String four;
    String correctAnswer;
}
```

Then in my adapter, I added the individual strings to an array

```
List<String> answerOptions = new ArrayList<>();
answerOptions.add(quiz.one);
answerOptions.add(quiz.two);
answerOptions.add(quiz.three);
answerOptions.add(quiz.four);
...
quizHolder.createRadioButtons(answerOptions.toArray(new String[0]));
...
```